# Copy Azure Storage Table Service data to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-table-storage

How can I copy huge amounts of data from Azure Storage Table Service to SQL Server using PowerShell?
AzTable which Microsoft recommends using does not support incremental load without underlying information about partition keys, and the documentation website is down...:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering this question myself, because I have lots of trouble findind a solution online, and would like to help other people with this crap.

```
$StorageAccountResourceGroup = "MyResourceGroup"
$StorageAccountName = "MyStorageAccount"
$TableName = "MyStorageTableName"
$SqlConnectionString = "MySqlConnectionString"
$BulkCopy = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy]::new()
$BulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "[myschema].[mytablename]"
$DataTable = <<Generate datatable from SQL-table>> # Code not included
Connect-AzAccount

$StorageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $StorageAccountResourceGroup -AccountName  $StorageAccountName | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.KeyName -eq "Key1"}).Value

$Context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

$CloudTable = (Get-AzStorageTable -Context $Context -Name $TableName).CloudTable

$TableQuery = [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableQuery]::new()
$Token = $null

BulkCounter = 0
do{
    $ReturnObject = $CloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmented($TableQuery, $Token)
    $Token = $ReturnObject.ContinuationToken



    foreach($Entry in $ReturnObject){
        $Row = $DataTable.NewRow()
        foreach($Column in $DataTable.Columns){
            if($Column.ColumnName -eq "TimeStamp"){
                $Value = $Entry.TimeStamp
            } elseif($Column.ColumnName -eq "RowKey"){
                $Value = $Entry.RowKey
            } elseif($Column.ColumnName -eq "PartitionKey"){
                $Value = $Entry.PartitionKey
            } else {
                if($Column.DataType -eq [System.Decimal]){
                    $Value = $Entry.Properties.$($Column.ColumnName).DoubleValue
                } elseif($Column.DataType -eq [System.String]){
                    $Value = $Entry.Properties.$($Column.ColumnName).StringValue
                } elseif($Column.DataType -eq [System.Guid]){
                    $Value = $Entry.Properties.$($Column.ColumnName).GuidValue
                } elseif($Column.DataType -eq [System.datetimeoffset]){
                    $Value = $Entry.Properties.$($Column.ColumnName).DateTimeOffsetValue
                } elseif($Column.DataType -eq [System.Int32]){
                    $Value = $Entry.Properties.$($Column.ColumnName).Int32Value
                } elseif($Column.DataType -eq [System.Int64]){
                    $Value = $Entry.Properties.$($Column.ColumnName).Int64Value
                } elseif($Column.DataType -eq [System.Boolean]){
                    $Value = $Entry.Properties.$($Column.ColumnName).BooleanValue
                } elseif($Column.DataType -eq [System.Binary]){
                    $Value = $Entry.Properties.$($Column.ColumnName).BinaryValue
                } 
            }
            if([System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Value)){
                $Value = [System.DBNull]::value
            }
            $Row.($Column.ColumnName) = $Value
        }
        $DataTable.Rows.Add($Row)
        $Counter++
        
    }
    $BulkCounter ++
    if($BulkCounter % 25 -eq 0 -and $BulkCounter -ne 0){
        $BulkCopy.WriteToServer($Datatable.CreateDataReader()) | Out-Null
        $Datatable.Clear() | Out-Null
        $BulkCounter = 0
    }
    
} while ($Token)

if($Datatable.rows.count -gt 0){
    $BulkCopy.WriteToServer($Datatable.CreateDataReader()) | Out-Null   
    $Datatable.Clear() | Out-Null
}
```

Here is also some functions for automatically generating tables from storage account tables:

```
function ConvertTo-SqlTypeFromEDM {
    param (
        $EDMType
    )
    if($EDMType -eq "String"){
        return "varchar(100)"
    } elseif($EDMType -eq "Guid"){
        return "uniqueidentifier"
    } elseif ($EDMType -eq "DateTime"){
        return "datetimeoffset(0)"
    } elseif ($EDMType -eq "Binary"){
        return "varbinary(max)"
    } elseif ($EDMType -eq "Int32"){
        return "int"
    } elseif ($EDMType -eq "Int64"){
        return "long"
    } elseif ($EDMType -eq "Double"){
        return "decimal(25,5)"
    } elseif ($EDMType -eq "Boolean"){
        return "bit"
    } else {
        throw "Tybe $EDMType not implemented"
    }
}


function Get-SqlQueryFromStorageTableSerivce {
    param(
        $CloudTable,
        $SchemaName
    )

    $Query = [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableQuery]::new()
    $Query.TakeCount = 1
    $Token = $null

    $Result = $CloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmented($Query, $Token)

    $TableName = $CloudTable.Name

    $TableString = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [$SchemaName].[$TableName]`n"
    $TableString += "CREATE TABLE [$SchemaName].[$TableName] (`n`t"

    $ColumnString = @()
    $TableKeys = @()
    if($Result.PartitionKey){
        $ColumnString += "[PartitionKey] varchar(100) NOT NULL"
        $TableKeys += "[PartitionKey]"
    }
    if($Result.RowKey){
        $ColumnString += "[RowKey] varchar(100) NOT NULL"
        $TableKeys += "[RowKey]"
    }
    if($Result.Timestamp){
        $ColumnString += "[Timestamp] datetimeoffset(0) NULL"
    }
    foreach($Column in $Result.Properties.Keys){
        $ColumnString += "[$Column] $(ConvertTo-SqlTypeFromEDM -EDMType $Result.Properties.$Column.PropertyType) NULL"
    }
    $TableString += $ColumnString -join ",`n`t"
    $TableString += "`nCONSTRAINT [PK_1_$($TableName)_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED`n"
    $TableString += "(`n`t" + ($TableKeys -join ",`n`t")
    $TableString += "`n)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF, DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE) ON [PRIMARY]"
    $TableString += "`n) ON [PRIMARY]`n"

    return $TableString
}
```